# How can I replace the auto keyword in this code?

Tags: c++, variables, types, auto

I am following this [tutorial](https://trungams.github.io/2020-08-23-a-simple-http-server-from-scratch/).  The following declaration found in [main.cc](https://github.com/trungams/http-server/blob/master/src/main.cc) has me intrigued:

```
auto say_hello = [](const HttpRequest& request) -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse response(HttpStatusCode::Ok);
    response.SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    response.SetContent("Hello, world\n");
    return response;
}
```

[image: img]

This is shown in the debugging window.

I wish to replace the `auto` keyword with the original data type.  I have tried the following but it fails:

```
HttpResponse say_hello = [](const HttpRequest& request) -> HttpResponse {...}
```

Could someone tell me why it is wrong?  What is the correct solution?  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: [Lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) doesn't really have a certain type that you can declare. `HttpResponse` is the return-type of the lambda function, not the type of the lambda itself. Do you mean that you want to *call* the lambda function, and initialize a variable with the result? That doesn't make sense in that context.

Comment: The original data type is not synonymous with the type of object you're declaring. You're declaring a lambda that returns am HttpResponse ; not an HttpResponse.

Comment: So you are saying the `auto` keyword is a must in this case?

Comment: If you want to create a callable object, and initialize it using a lambda, so that you can pass it around to other functions and call it later, then `auto` is definitely the right choice.

Comment: You can use `std::function<HttpResponse(const HttpRequest&)>` or `HttpResponse(*)(const HttpRequest&)`, but that's not the type of the lambda. That's the type the lambda can be converted to.

Comment: A lambda is a *voldemort* type; you can't say its name.  You can store it in a `std::function`.  You can get the type after-the-fact, `using say_hello_t = decltype(say_hello);`.  You can pass it as a templated function parameter, but you'll need to get your feet wet with templates.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's important to know the 3 following methods when working with lambdas.
The three firsts do essentially the same thing: storing the lambda for future use.
The other seems to be what you expect from your code: you directly call the lambda and get the result, so the return type is the type returned by the lambda.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    // Auto store the lambda
    auto auto_keyword = [](int a) -> int
    { return a; };
    std::cout << auto_keyword(42) << std::endl;

    // std::function store the lambda
    std::function<int(int)> std_function = [](int a) -> int
    { return a; };
    std::cout << std_function(42) << std::endl;

    // raw function pointer
    int (*raw_fptr)(int) = [](int a) -> int
    { return a; };
    std::cout << raw_fptr(42) << std::endl;

    // direct call to the lambda. (what you expect from your question)
    std::cout << ([](int a) -> int{ return a; })(42) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

A lot of things happen here, and I suggest you to read at least [this page from the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a lambda expression is an anonymous function object and it doesn't have a named type. However, sometimes we can use type erasure. If a lambda expression doesn't capture any arguments like your example, it can convert to function pointer implicitly. If a lambda expression captures some arguments, it can convert to `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), (emphasize mine)

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique **unnamed** non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type

As the type of a lambda expression is an unnamed type you cannot use it in a declaration. That is the reason why `auto` is the common usage for a lambda.

If you want to be more explicit for the arguments and return type, you can store the lambda in a `std::function` variable:

```
std::function<HttpResponse(const HttpRequest&)> say_hello = ...
```

But `std::function` is still not really the type of the lambda (which is unnamed...), it is just the type of a variable which is able to hold that lambda, as it could old the address of a plain function.

---

For further reference, draft n4860 for C++20 says at 7.5.5.1 Closure types [expr.prim.lambda.closure] §1

> The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union
> class type, called the closure type ...

Comment: Yes, you are right to insist on the fact that the lambda does not have a type in itself. This is missing in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From C++ standard

> [C++11: 5.1.2/3]: **The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the
> type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type
> — called the closure type —** whose properties are described below. This
> class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared
> in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that
> contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

In short each instance of a lambda is its own unique unnamed type.

> [C++11: 5.1.2/5]: The closure type for a lambda-expression has a
> public inline function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and
> return type are described by the lambda-expression’s
> parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively.

Since lambda has function call operator defined you can assign it to std::function

> [C++11: 5.1.2/6]: The closure type for a lambda-expression with no
> lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion
> function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return
> types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned
> by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that,
> when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s
> function call operator.

If the lambda does not capture anything it can be converted to a function pointer.